# Want only single true or false value from observers

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have used one messagBox from p-toast. When i click on delete i want to take yes or no value and then it will hit the api for deleting the item. and on no it will not do anything. This thing is working but when I click on 1st item then i click no and then i click on 2nd item and then in messagebox i click on yes, after this it is deleting 1st and 2nd both items. I jst want to delete the current item.

**messagebox.service.ts:**

```
public messageSource = new BehaviorSubject(false);   currentMessage =
 this.messageSource.asObservable();

   public _msgBoxSubject: EventEmitter<boolean> = new
 EventEmitter<boolean>();   public confirmResponse: boolean = false;  
 response: boolean = false;

   show() {
     this.messageSource.next(false);
     this.response = true;
     this._msgBoxSubject.emit(this.response);   }

   onYes(value) {
     this.messageSource.next(value);
     this.confirmResponse = value;   }

   onNo(value1) {
     this.confirmResponse = value1;   }

  hide() {
     this.response = false;
     this._msgBoxSubject.emit(this.response);   }

   getMsgBoxEmitter() {
     return this._msgBoxSubject;   }
```

**messagebox.component.ts:**

```
 ngOnInit() {
     this._msgBoxService.getMsgBoxEmitter().subscribe((value: boolean) => {
       this.messageService.clear();
       this.messageService.add({ key: 'c', sticky: true, severity: 'warn', summary: 'Are you sure?', detail: 'Confirm to proceed' });
     });    }

   onConfirm() {
     this.messageService.clear('c');
     this._msgBoxService.onYes(true);   }

   onReject() {
     this.messageService.clear('c');   }
```

**emailmaster.component.ts:
(I am calling this function on delete button click)**

```
  deleteEmail(ID: Email) {
        this._msgBoxService.show();
        this._msgBoxService.currentMessage.subscribe(response1 => {
           if (response1 === true) {
             this._masterservice.deleteEmail(ID).subscribe(data => {
               this._toasterService.showMessage('Email deleted successfully', 'Success Message', 'success');
               if (data) {
                 this.GetEmails();
               }
             });
           }
        });
       }
```

I just want current item to be deleted on yes click from messagebox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as another answer has already suggested, the issue I think is that your subscribe in the deleteEmail function for currentMessage is never unsubscribed from, so it is living on from the previous attempt

```
deleteEmail(ID: Email) {
        this._msgBoxService.show();
        this._msgBoxService.currentMessage.subscribe(response1 => {
           if (response1 === true) {
             this._masterservice.deleteEmail(ID).subscribe(data => {
               this._toasterService.showMessage('Email deleted successfully', 'Success Message', 'success');
               if (data) {
                 this.GetEmails();
               }
             });
           }
        });
       }
```

example of the current flow.

your call to deleteEmail pops a confirm and your code subscribes to the answer, looking for a true.

you click no (false), and the confirm goes away, but the subscribe lives on still listening.

your next call to delete email pops a confirm and your code again subscribes to the answer and now there are two subscribes listening.

you click yes (true), and both subscribes leap into action sending delete requests for both the first and the second item.

---

The other poster was right in their thinking but their approach won't work because your service only emits when something is true.  It never says when it's false.  So trying to take(1) means it will just sit there and wait until something says yes.

so we will need to make a few minor changes to get this working.

## step 1 use the take(1)

```
    this._msgBoxService.currentMessage
        .pipe(take(1)) // this completes the observable after hearing 1 value from it
        .subscribe(response1 => {
```

## step 2 do something on reject

```
   onReject() {
     this.messageService.clear('c');   
     this._msgBoxService.onNo(false); // send the onNo when rejected
```

## step 3 emit the value when onNo is called

```
   onNo(value1) {
     this.messageSource.next(value1); // when onNo called, emit the value so old subscribers can complete
     this.confirmResponse = value1;   }
```

## also recommended to remove the emitting of a false value on show, as this could confuse things

```
   show() {
     // this.messageSource.next(false); // remove this line to avoid hearing it's emit 
     this.response = true;
```

Comment: By this code, If I delete item 1 and click NO on msgbox, it wont delete...
If I click on item 2 and click YES on msgbox, it wont delete...
If I click on item 3...it will delete item 2 and then show msgbox...
I debugged it and I found that the observable is not waiting for current value..

Comment: I was wondering if you would run into that or not.  The BehaviourSubject retains the latest value.  When you are subscribing, it may be getting the value at the time, and then completing (due to the take(1)).  My suggestion is try the code above and change your BehaviourSubject to be just Subject, which is same but does not retain a value.

Comment: You are real genius...changing BehaviourSubject to be just Subject works. Thanks alot buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Your `deleteEmail` method isn't unsubscribing from the `currentMessage` Observable. Try something like the following:

```js
deleteEmail(ID: Email) {
  this._msgBoxService.show();
  this._msgBoxService.currentMessage.pipe(
    filter(response1 => response1), // only allows true values through
    take(1), // takes one emission per subscription and then completes
    mergeMap(() => this._masterservice.deleteEmail(ID)), // mergeMap can be used safely because you're only getting one emission
    tap(() => this._toasterService.showMessage('Email deleted successfully', 'Success Message', 'success')),
    filter(data => !!data), // only emissions where data exists here will continue
    tap(() => this.GetEmails())
  ).subscribe();
}
```

I would also advise adding error handling, because if anything here fails, you don't find out about it. You could, for example, add a `catchError` block.